# Java Unchecked exceptions thrown out of main

Tags: java, exception

If I throw an unchecked exception out of main, will that always not crash the program. I am asking because I am running a GUI, and it currently does not crash the program. Will they normally crash or only in certain situations? Does the same go for checked exceptions an GUIs

Stack overflow crashed on me so I didn't realize this question got posted twice, I felt it would be wrong to have two copies. This is the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either checked of unchecked exception will crash the main thread. However, it doesn't mean that JVM will exit. JVM exits when no non-daemons thread are running. If you are running a GUI app, then the UI event loop is a non daemon thread and it will keep JVM running until it completes.

Comment: So if the main thread exits, and I throw an exception is just gets ignored whether check or unchecked?

Comment: It doesn't get ignored. It crashes your main thread. The main thread execution stops at the point you throw the exception and it exits abnormally (in JLS lingo). Also, note that you will need to declare a checked Exception in main if you are raising it in the main Thread. Example: public static void main(String... args) throws Exception.

Comment: Doesn't the main thread terminate after I create the GUI, if there are not other task it must perform? Or when you say main thread are u referring to the currently running thread? Not the thread that runs from main method

Comment: Yes, the main thread terminates after the main body completes. Normally or abnormally. I am referring the main thread as the thread which executes the main method of a Java program. The UI thread typically runs an event loop and it doesn't exit if some exception occurs because it's caught and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> If I throw an unchecked exception out of main, will that always not crash the program.

In the technical sense, a crash occurs when the JVM encounters a serious internal error and outputs a crash dump containing register contents and all sorts of other obscure stuff into a file.

When the main thread exits due to an uncaught exception, that is not a crash.  It is (from the JVM's perspective) an orderly shutdown.

Chandra's answer explains how a JVM shutdown normally happens, though he did not mention that calling `System.exit()` is the other way to initiate an orderly shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the code in the main method with try-catch (Throwable t). That catches everything.